# Optimizing JQuery based animation by caching selector result?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've made an animation who's based on the following jQuery functions : hide(), show(), animate().

This animation consumes a lot of CPU (the Flash like CPU usage), Chrome tells me that (through the CSS selector profiling tool) that I've a lot of similar CSS selectors usage (CSS Selector Profile).

Does these selectors are those used only by the rendering engine ? Does this include also the jQuery node search while using $() (I assumed it's called by hide(), show() or animate()) ?

If yes to the second question, how could I override this function to cache some node ? (by hard coding a few selectors whose result won't change in my animation logics).

EDIT : I'm implementing a transition between frames, each frame as a Ken Burns effect on its background

EDIT2 : here's a jQuery plugin that use CSS3 for animation when possible https://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced

Comment: If you're concerned about performance I think you should take into account the idea to use CSS3 transitions/animations to achieve some effects so to make the GPU work in place of the CPU

Comment: It's more of a matter is assigning the selector to a variable and using the variable instead of re-running the selector. Showing your code would help a bit in determining some optimization possibilities.

Comment: @F.Calderan +1 I didn't knew the CSS3 use the GPU, a good thing to know. I'm gonna try this approach but for complex animation it might be not possible.

Comment: @Diodeus : my problem is that I use jQuery functions (like animate), I'm not doing many calls myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing alot of jquery animations using code like the following:

```
$('div.myclass').show();
 ...
$('div.myclass').hide();
....
$('div.myclass').toggle();
```

You might want to look at chaining your jquery selections:

```
$('div.myclass').show().addClass('sdf').children('li').slideToggle()
```

or assigning the selector to a variable and reusing that variable

```
 var $ele = $('div.myclass');
 $ele.show();
 ...
$ele.hide();
....
$ele.toggle();
```

Comment: As previously mentionned in comments, I'm already taking care about such things.